# Check the table that has changed in change tracking in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, command

I have to use change tracking to mark changes in the database, now I just want to get the tables have changed the SQL statement will look like?

Comment: Can you please give us sample of required output..like you need only table names for which data has been changed or corresponding sql query which changed the data..

Comment: I just took the name row table that has been updated or insert in the database

Answer (score 0):

This one is good article about it..but make sure you have understood overheads or drawbacks of it...        [SQL Server - Change Tracking (CT)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/537649/SQL-Server-Change-Tracking-CT)